# Oracle equivalent recursive OUTER APPLY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have some SQL Server code to migrate to Oracle 11g. There are a lot of recursive `OUTER APPLY` statements like this one:

```
select  a.colA
       ,bb.retB
       ,cc.retC
from tableA a

outer apply
(
select funcB(b.colB) as retB
from tableB b
where b.colA = a.colA
) bb

outer apply
(
select funcC(bb.retB, c.colC) as retC
from tableC c
where c.colB = bb.retB
) cc
```

......

The key point is that OUTER APPLY block bb depends on the result of a, and `OUTER APPLY` block cc depends on the result of `OUTER APPLY` block bb, and so on. How can I rewrite these structures in Oracle database and keep them as readable as in SQL Server? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't recursive; I guess you could call it iterative...

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is technically correct, it is inaccurate on the following basis.  An outer join will try to fetch the data set requested fully and then filter according to the join whereas the outer apply applies the filter to the record set being fetched thus resulting in a faster query.  This may not be noticeable for simple queries but for very complex joins, a outer apply is much more efficient than a outer join.

Answer (score -2):

you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of OUTER APPLY, both functionality are same.

```
select  a.colA
       ,bb.retB
       ,cc.retC
from tableA a

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
select funcB(b.colB) as retB
from tableB
) b on b.colA = a.colA
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
select funcC(bb.retB, c.colC) as retC
from tableC 
where 
) c on c.colB = bb.retB;
```

Comment: An OUTER APPLY is not the same as an LEFT OUTER JOIN. In the latter you cannot use references to the left part in the select of the right part. See https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#outer-apply-join for details and usage.